# Scope within an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I'm coming from an Actionscript background and (very late to the party) I am trying to learn JavaScript. I am going through this [AngularJS - Video Tutorial For Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-lPviKS_WM) on YouTube (it's pretty good) and saw something really basic that I don't understand.

At line 5 the `var workcount` is defined. Then two anonymous functions are defined and returned in an object. The functions reference `workcount` but isn't `workcount` in a different scope? Is this like `blocks` in Objective-C where local vars remain accessible within the block. Is there a name for what this is?

**Or** if a function "knows about" vars previously defined in its scope, would the function `task2` "know about" `task1`?

It bugs me that I can't make sense of this.

**Update:** Thanks for all the replies. I get it now – and while I have seen the term "closures" before, I never understood it (it seems a not very descriptive term. In reading up, I saw the term "stack-frames" and then the light bulb lit up: stack... frame of reference);

---

```
var createWorker = function(){

  var workCount = 0;

  var task1 = function(){
    workCount += 1;
    console.log("task1" , workCount);
  };

  var task2 = function(){
    workCount += 1;
    console.log("task2" , workCount);
  };

  return {
    job1: task1,
    job2:task2
  }
};

worker=createWorker();

worker.job1();

worker.job2();
```

Output:

```
task1 1
task2 2
```

Comment: If you post images, make sure the same content is available as text (which obviates the use of images). Not everyone can see attached images.

Comment: This seems to be a simple case of not understanding closures, see [*MDN: Closures*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [*SO: How do JavaScript closures work?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just note that the variable and the two anonymous functions are wrapped inside the same function (let's call it a parent function). So the scope of this variable is available within this parent function.

So now this variable acts as a global variable for these two inner functions **But the scope is limited to the parent function**. Both the inner functions share the same variable.. Changing the value of the variable in one function will have effect in other function too..

So taking the logic in the post Let's say we execute task1 and task2 one after the other. The variable is initially set to 0. Then in your task1 it's incremented by one. Which makes the variable value 1 (0 + 1). Now in task two also its increased by one, making its value 2 (1 + 1).

This scope concept is called as **closure** in JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

This is called a closure in JavaScript.

The scope of a closure in JavaScript is lexical, which means that everything that is contained within the function the closure belongs to, has access to any variable that is in it

Basically createWorker is a scope and since task 1 and task 2 are declared inside createWorker they have access to all the variables declared in createWorkers scope.

But `createWorker` does not have access to any variables declared inside task 1 and task 2.

Comment: Q: "Is there a name for what this is?". A: "This in javascript is called a closure. " nuff said +1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, functions are aware of everything in their scope, including each other.

There are two parts to your question.

The second part is easy to answer first: all variables and functions in a scope are "[hoisted](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)," allowing you to use a variable before you declare it:

```
x = 5;
var x;
console.log(x); // Gives 5
```

Back to the first part of your question: in terms of scope, I won't expand too much on it since it is a widely covered topic on this and other sites. [w3schools has a good guide on this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Basically, it boils down to global and local scope. Global scope works as you might imagine, with the variable (or function) being available globally:

```
var x = 10;
function foo() {
  console.log('Global scope! ' + x);
}
```

Local scope is, basically, for everything within a closure (a topic well beyond this question), which functions are:

```
function foo() {
  bar(); // This will work, since foo and bar share scope
  foobar(); // This will not work: foobar is only in scope within bar
}

function bar() {
  function foobar() {
    console.log('foobar');
  };

  console.log('bar');
  foobar(); // This will work, since foobar is defined within bar's local scope
}
```

Things get a little more complicated with `var` declarations. This is being greatly simplified by the ES6 `let` declaration. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword).

And by the way, while your functions are anonymous, they aren't really since you are saving references to them. Functionally, the two examples below are perfectly equivalent:

```
// These give the exact same result
function foo() {}
var foo = function() {}

// You can use either by calling
foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

This code illustrates how it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Closure JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var createWorker = function () {
            var workCount = 0;
            var task1 = function () {
                var t = t || 0;
                workCount += 1;
                console.log("task1: " + workCount);
                console.log("task1 t: " + (t++));
            }
            var task2 = function () {
                var t = t || 0;
                workCount += 1;
                console.log("task2: " + workCount);
                console.log("task2 t: " + (t++));
            }
            return {
                job1: task1,
                job2: task2
            };
        }
        var app = new createWorker();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="task1" onclick="app.job1()" />
    <input type="button" value="task2" onclick="app.job2()" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Console output after several clicks on buttons:

```
task1: 1
task1 t: 0
task1: 2
task1 t: 0
task2: 3
task2 t: 0
task2: 4
task2 t: 0
```

It easy to see that task1 and task2 know about their parent scope and know nothing about each other and about their previous execution.
This way ball bounces.

Answer (score 2):

You can write write your code as in below and javascript will interpret it the same.

```
var createWorker = function(){
  var workCount, task1, task2;

  workCount = 0;

  task1 = function(){
    workCount += 1;
    console.log("task1" , workCount);
  };

  task2 = function(){
    workCount += 1;
    console.log("task2" , workCount);
  };

  return {
    job1: task1,
    job2:task2
  }
};
```

What happens here is, variables are defined at the top of the enclosing function block. No matter in what order they are defined. So not only `task2` knows about `task1`, `task1` also knows about `task2`. However order of assignments in important. Consider the code:

```js
function foo1() {
  console.log("foo1: " + a);
  var a = "Hello";
}

function foo2() {
  var a = "Hello";
  console.log("foo2: " + a);
}

function foo3() {
  console.log("foo3: " + a);
  let a = "Hello";
}

function foo4() {
  console.log("foo4: " + b);
}
var b = 5;

foo1(); // undefined
foo2(); // Hello

try {
  foo3(); // Throws ReferenceError
} catch (e) {
  console.log("foo3: " + e.message);
}
foo4(); // 5
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

- When `foo1` tries to use `a`, it was defined but it was not assigned.
- `foo3` uses `let` instead of `var`. `let` is more intuitive for some
  coming from other programming languages. But be careful as it is part
  of ES6 specification and not widely supported yet.
- `foo4` works since `b` was defined before `foo4` was
  defined. `b` was    assigned before `foo4` was invoked.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has some interesting variable scoping rules. Here is a quick overview:

```
x = 0; // Global, as no "var" keyword preceeds it. Btw: var is optional!
var x =  0; // This is scoped to it's parent fn. Child fn's can use it.
let x = 0; // This is similar to var, but has a special use case. (See below.)
```

As an added bonus, this next line of code looks like it's a variable declaration, but it's not. It defines a constant. It's part of the [EcmaScript 2015](http://es6-features.org/#Constants) spec, AKA ES6. Here's [what's new in ES6](http://es6-features.org/#Constants).

```
const x = 0; // This is a constant (locked variable) and can't be changed.
```

While both `var` & `let` are accessible by their immediate function & their children functions, here is where they're different: The `let` keyword can allow someone to make duplicates variables with the same name, from both inside of the parent & child functions! It just makes JS stranger!

Since workCount is defined inside of the parent `createWorker` function with the "var" keyword, then the `task1` & `task2` functions can change it's value, as they are children functions.

Check out the MDN specs on how the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) & [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keywords work.

So the answers to some of your questions are:

1. No, it's in the same parent "createWorker" function scope.
2. Unknown as I don't write ObjectiveC code. Someone else can answer that one.
3. Yes & No: Yes, because it can tell that task1 is a function, but No, because the code in task2's function block can't see inside of task1's function block.

Answer (score 0):

task 2 would not know about variables created within task 1, task 1 and task 2 do know about workCount.